# UIPopoverController is showing on the other button

Tags: iphone, ios6, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

When UIButton is tapped to display UIPopovercontroller, it is showing on the other UIbarbuttonitemand it is showing blank black opaque UIPopovercontroller.

Here is my implemented code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

UIButton *btnAction;

BookmarkViewController* bookmarkVC = [[BookmarkViewController alloc] init];

_buttonPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                initWithContentViewController:bookmarkVC];

_buttonPopoverController.delegate = self;

CGRect popoverFrame = btnAction.frame;
[_buttonPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 355) animated:NO];

//only required if using delegate methods

[_buttonPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame
                                              inView:self.view
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                            animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How are you setting `UIButton *btnAction` to the correct button?

Comment: using storyboard to connect buttonTapped

Comment: That is probably your issue then. You need to select the button based on some property of the `(id)sender` that is supplied to the function, or just assign the sender to the button: `*btnAction = sender`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to assing `sender` to `btnAction`

that is     `UIButton *btnAction=(UIButton *)sender;`

try this,

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

UIButton *btnAction=(UIButton *)sender;


UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *bookmarkVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BookmarkViewController"];

_buttonPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                initWithContentViewController:bookmarkVC];

_buttonPopoverController.delegate = self;

CGRect popoverFrame = btnAction.frame;
[bookmarkVC setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 355)];

//only required if using delegate methods

[_buttonPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame
                                              inView:self.view
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                            animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: with this change now it is showing under correct uibutton but why it is showing blank. It should show table view with add, edit and done button.

Comment: check updated answer:
`BookmarkViewController* bookmarkVC = [[BookmarkViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BookmarkViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: this change crashes app when uibutton is tapped to show uipopovercontroller

Comment: bookmark view controller is in the storyboard but it is attached via button tapped action method

Comment: check updated answer. and check your storyboard name and viewcontroller is same as given by me.

Comment: still it crashes app??

Comment: BookmarkViewController segue is not attached because when i try to attach segue it doesn't shows popover segue option to select so i attached bookmarkviewcontroller via button tapped action method. or i should make a separate xib file for bookmarkviewcontroller for this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35598/discussion-between-viruss-mca-and-user1120133)

Comment: thanks it is working now appreciate help. i didn't mention storyboard identity name i only specified custom class name

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *btnAction=(UIButton*) sender;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here

```
[_buttonPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame
                                              inView:self.view
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                            animated:YES];
```

where `presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame` should be actually the **rect** of the popover not of the `UIButton` and also the **btnAction** has no frame you haven't allocated it also and you are performing `CGRect popoverFrame = btnAction.frame;`

It should be like

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 50.0) inView:self.view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to [the documentation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPopoverController/presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:) `rect: The rectangle in view at which to anchor the popover window.`

Comment: [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 50.0) inView:self.view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];